# Generics and Loose Coupling: Can Class<T> be decoupled without type assumptions?

Tags: .net, generics, reflection, dependency-injection, loose-coupling

I have been playing with loosely coupling my data access layer.  I found the Dependency injection process quite helpful, but ran into a bit of a conundrum when considering the use of generics.

Is there a way to get a class that supports a generic type parameter to truly be both decoupled and type safe?  My concern is that even if you write to a common interface if the derived type down the road is different than the entities you originally coded to then you can run into some nasty runtime errors that the compiler may not catch.

The issue is that when I write the code to get the data from the database and hydrate my object I am faced with a conundrum when trying to implement it on the next layer up.  If I pass in an class such as Foo2 below I can break my code as there is no "implicit" conversion.  I had been working with reflection to try and loosen things up, but I keep coming back to the issue that when getting the data from the database I need to hydrate a concrete type.  That type then creates issues with casting and type assurance.  Additionally, if I wanted to abstract all the methods for all the many types in my entity library I can do this with reflection, but I still run into the issue that a generic can only make type assurances on explicitly "where T : ISomeInterface" statements.  Finally, this model would break down if we have more derived types down the road or types that branch off from interfaces to form new types.  Thinking I would need to implement new Data Access Objects for every single type ever made would force changes in the Data Access Layer.  That breaks the definition of loose coupling in my mind.

All of this seems to force me back to the question - Can generics be used in a truly loose coupled way?  If so, what references can you offer?

Simplified Example:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    // stuff for state and methods ...
}
public interface IRepository<T> where T : IEntity
{
    void Save(out int id, T obj);
    T Load(int id);
}
public interface IFoo : IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    //All other IEntities goodness
    //Some new goodness specific to Foo
}
//Concrete Entities:
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    // blah blah
}
public class Foo2 : IFoo
{
    // new blah blah
}

public class FooRepository : IRepository<Foo> //OOPS, Looks like we have settled in on a concrete type!
{

    public void Save(out int id, Foo obj)
    {
        // ADO.NET code to access Sql ...
        id = 1;// this would actually be the result of the Sql insert output parameter
        return;
    }

    public Foo Load(int id)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        // ADO.Net code to access Sql
        return foo;
    }
}
```

So how would you deal with code that could handle any IFoo derived object and still be able to return a fully formed concrete type regardless of what programmers do down the road?  Is it best to ditch the generic portion and stick with the dependency injection?  Any references, guidance, etc. would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the problem you're running into here, you can always use `typeof` (or perhaps it's a different operator/method) to get the dynamic type of your object.  This way you can always perform checks before running into some casting error.

You can set the concrete type restriction to your top-level type, but that really defeats the purpose of generics.

Otherwise, I don't really see how to overcome your problem. If you use generics, the point is to add loose coupling and generic operations that are agnostic on type.  The only way you can retrieve it is you typeof and then recast, catching the edge cases to prevent casting errors.  Regarding your question:

> Can generics be used in a truly loose coupled way?

I don't quite understand what you mean?   Semantically from your question, of course you can.  That is in fact one of the purposes of generics.

> So how would you deal with code that could handle any IFoo derived object and still be able to return a fully formed concrete type regardless of what programmers do down the road?

This is also quite vague.  I could write:

```
public SomeType method(IFoo obj)
{
...
}
```

And this would still handle any IFoo.  You don't need generics for this.  If you want to return the type of whatever you passed in concretely, then:

```
public T method<T>(IFoo obj) where T:IFoo
{
    return (T)obj;
}
```

Hope this helps. LMK if I get something wrong.

Comment: I know the question is not 100% fully formed.  I did not want to get too deep into the weeds on this as the overarching comments you made do align with some of what I was playing with.  Your last structure is very interesting.  If I recall correctly, however, if your are enforcing a type constraint on a class you are not allowed to then enforce conditions on the methods. Part of the issue is I have been playing with a more complex reflective class that would let me pass in any generic type and then return the "Save" and Load methods from the underlying Data Access Objects.  I have a clash.

Comment: ... the clash is that DataAccessClass<T> where T : IBaseObject. IEntity : IBaseObject, and IFoo : IEntity.  This produces the proper chain I need for hierarchy, but if I try to then call the "Load" and "Save" methods on IFoo derived classes from inside the DataAccessClass<T> and use reflection to decide which DAO classes to call methods on there is no way to enforce the type safety other than throwing exceptions if, as you said, typeof() does not equate to true.  Maybe I would be better off not aggrigating these as much and keep them seperated into their own classes / methods for data access.

Comment: I guess I should add that the use this code in the layer above would be:  DataAccessClass<Foo>.Load(int) and the choice between all Entity types is then decided in the DAL's DataAccessClass.  Names have all been oversimplified of course, but Entities can be a many different goods (e.g. book, music, computer, ...).

Comment: If you have thoughts on proper patterns or abstractions I would appreciate it.  I may need to rethink design (e.g. insert a abstract factory pattern or something).

Comment: There is a difference between type constraint and method arguments.  Things that go in between <> are type constraints (as in, types you pass in to do whatever you want with).  Your methods are any actual variable.  You can thing of <T> as just another argument accepter but just for types.  I.E. method<A,B,C,D>()

Comment: In which case you are saying I could have a class level constraint, then later define a seperate generic for the method that forces a local method level constraint that has the concrete constraint I need.  Is this accurate?  class SomeClass<T1> where T1: IProduct ... public T2 DoSomething<T2> where T2 : class, T1, IKeyBoard, new() ...  Is this a fair statement?

Comment: Right, class level constraints and method level constraints work very similarly.  It's just a difference of where variable scope goes.

Comment: Ahh.  So it is illegal to have a constraint defined twice, but you can have a second generic that inherrits the first at the method level.  Interesting.  That is apoint I missed.  Thank you.  I will have to experement with this.

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit to being a bit confused by your conundrum; I'm not sure what it could be.

A repository that produces concrete types obviously has to know how to create them.  Why not create a repository per type such that each implements `IRepository<IFoo>`?  That way you can leave the concrete implementation to your DI container's configuration.

For example, in ninject I'd write something akin to

```
Bind<IRepository<IFoo>>.To<Foo2Repository>()
```

to set that up.  If you need more fine-grained control, most containers that I know of support some manner of scoping such that the binding is only in force in certain conditions.

Have I misunderstood something, or does this address your concern?

Comment: Interesting ... I will look into Bind and ninject a bit deeper.  Everything I have been doing in this project has been from scratch so may benefit from exploring more.  I have avoided the IOC containers a bit to see if I could err on the side of performance but an quickly getting to the point of considering these tools.

Comment: I think that one of the big benefits of following a DI pattern as you have been is that you *can* use an IoC container - testability obviously being the other.  The performance hit is negligible, in my experience.

Comment: I may need to consider this.  The complexity of the system is one thing I am going to need to abstract to allow ease of use.  The library of types alone will have several categories.  Each category can have several concrete types.  Each concrete type will have exactly two other derivations.  That is why I tried to keep this question simple.  The arechitecture will be a 3 tier application with a WCF service connecting the domain layers to the presentation layers.  Back end is SQL for now, but I want to keep the abiltiy to choose.  It will need to scale as I expect to drive a lot of uses ...

Comment: ...I suppose the fact I am deploying the domain layer as a service I can loadbalance across instances for scalability.  In what context have you used IoC containers?  Which do you find the best? (performance balanced with ease of use / maintainability).  Any words of warning?  PS - By scalable I am talking millions of users

Answer (score 0):

You could define the common stuff in

```
class BaseFooRepository<TFoo> : IRepository<TFoo> where TFoo : IFoo
```

and then put the more specific code in

```
class Foo2Repository : BaseFooRepository<Foo2>
```